# Assign same value to other columns using Hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Basically, I just need to assign the same value of EMPLOYEE_ID field to the other columns (PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID & PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS_ID) of EMPLOYEE table.

Details below:

Annotated class

```
    @SequenceGenerator(name="generator", sequenceName="EMPLOYEE_ID_SEQ")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="generator")
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(name="PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int profileEmployeeNameId;

    @Column(name="PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int profileEmployeeStatusId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SHORT_ID")
    @Where(clause = "ELEMENT_TYPE_CD like 'EMPLOYEE_%'")
    private Set<Profile> profile;
```

DDL

```
    EMPLOYEE
      EMPLOYEE_ID (Primary key)
      PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID
      PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS_ID

    PROFILE TABLE 
      PROFILE_ID (Primary key)
      ELEMENT_TYPE_CD (Possible values are: EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_STATUS)
      SHORT_ID
      DESCRIPTION
```

PROFILE table is joined with Employee table by SHORT_ID = EMPLOYEE_ID.

I know PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID & PROFILE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS_ID are redundant, but this is how the DBA desgined it. Or maybe I don't see the purpose of this design yet.

Is there a way to do it using annotation? Otherwise, what is the best solution for it?

Comment: Do you want to these columns always contain the same value? what's the got?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I would annotate a method in the entity class with @PrePersist where i would set the someOtherColumnId = employeeId (I guess these columns are in the same Entity class?)

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Yes, they will always have the same value

Comment: @maress Yes, they are in the same Entity class